# only can insert first and second value other value cannot insert in database. how to solve this?

Tags: php, mysql

```
  <?php
   require_once "config.php";
   if(isset($_POST['save'])){
   $values = array();
   for($i=0 ; $i <count($_POST['working']); $i++) {
    $values[] = '("' . $_POST['working']['day'][$i] . '","' . 
    $_POST['working']['status'][$i] . '")'; }
    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO working_day(day,status) VALUES " . implode(',', 
    $values);
    $result4=mysqli_query($connection,$sql4);}
   ?>
<form id="sendform" method="post" action="">

<input type="text" value="Monday" id="day" name="working[day][]" readonly />
<input type="text" value="" id="status" name="working[status][]" />


<input type="text" value="Tuesday" id="day" name="working[day][]" readonly />
<input type="text" value="" id="status" name="working[status][]" />

<input type="text" value="w" id="day" name="working[day][]" readonly />
<input type="text" value="" id="status" name="working[status][]"  />

<input type="text" value="T" id="day" name="working[day][]" readonly />
<input type="text" value="" id="status" name="working[status][]"  />

<input type="text" value="F" id="day" name="working[day][]" readonly />
<input type="text" value="" id="status" name="working[status][]" />

<input type="text" value="S" id="day" name="working[day][]" readonly />
<input type="text" value="" id="status" name="working[status][]"  />

<input type="text" value="S" id="day" name="working[day][]" readonly />
<input type="text" value="" id="status" name="working[status][]" />

<input type="submit" value="Send" name="save" />
</form>
```

**why this code only can insert first day&status and second day&status into the database ? The for loop count[i] cannot count another value. how to solve this problem? **

Comment: What does error reporting tell you? What are the values being passed in? What is the query that is executed? Hard to tell as is. Also you are open to SQL injections. Use the prepared statements and parameterize the query.

Comment: no any error message. when i submit the form only can get array[0] and array[1] value insert to database other cannot get

Comment: Use the `mysqli` error reporting function. It sounds like you are not accessing the right level. I would do `day[]` and `status[]` rather than the multilevel arrays. Rather than just executing your query. Output it as it is generated and see where you're going wrong. No point in execution the incorrect query. Comment out the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way is given below :-

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $values = array();
    for($i=0 ; $i <count($_POST['working']['day']); $i++) {
        $values[] = '("' . $_POST['working']['day'][$i] . '","' . $_POST['working']['status'][$i] . '")'; 
    }
    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO working_day(day,status) VALUES " . implode(',', $values);
    $result4=mysqli_query($connection,$sql4);
}
```

Comment: if insert more than two different value also like this?

Comment: depend on the situation. i am not understanding your case clearly. please explain more or show me the code.

Comment: like this $values[] = '("' . $_POST['working']['day'][$i] . '","' . $_POST['working']['start_time'][$i] . '","' . $_POST['working']['end_time'][$i] . '","' . $_POST['working']['status'][$i] . '")';